# Strange as.Date() behavior

Tags: r, coercion, type-coercion

I'm using R 4.2.1 with all packages updated to the latest version.
The two lines below differ only in the order of the elements in a concatenated vector, yet the output is completely different.

```
as.Date(c(Sys.Date(), "2020-09-09"))
as.Date(c("2020-09-09", Sys.Date()))
```

The output is:

```
> as.Date(c(Sys.Date(), "2020-09-09"))
[1] "2022-09-16" "2020-09-09"
> as.Date(c("2020-09-09", Sys.Date()))
[1] "2020-09-09" NA
```

The first line correctly coerces the system date as a string, and the second line coerces it first as a numeric value and then as a string, but I have never before run into a situation where coercion in R depends on the order of elements in a vector...

Can someone explain to me why coercion rules behave this way and where I can read more about it...

And what can I do in a situation when the type of elements inside `c()` is not known a priori?

Thank you!

Comment: You can see the same thing without the `as.Date`; Sys.Date() is coerced to a number string like "19251" if it comes 2nd.

Comment: FWIW `as.character(unclass(Sys.Date()))` is "19251" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `c()` unclasses each argument before combining them (`unclass(Sys.Date())` is 19251 [as of today]); this is because "all attributes except names are removed" by (at least the default version of) `c()`, **which includes the class**.

The reason for the difference in orders is that `c()` is an S3 generic function, which means that it dispatches on the class of its **first argument**, so `c(<date>, <character>)` calls `c.Date()`, while `c(<character>, <date>)` calls the generic version of `c()` (which falls through to a primitive function in C which I don't want to bother digging through).

The code of `c.Date`:

```r
function (..., recursive = FALSE) 
.Date(c(unlist(lapply(list(...), function(e) unclass(as.Date(e))))))
```

in other words, it coerces everything to a date, *then* unclasses it, *then* turns the vector back to dates once everything is concatenated ...

A possible workaround/solution is to call `c.Date()` explicitly, if you know that's what you want ...